# jQuery Fancybox working locally but not on webhost

Tags: jquery, html

My jQuery Fancybox works perfectly on my local computer, but it doesn't work now my website is live on 000webhost. I cannot find any answers as to why!

My website is : sarahmeasom.com

I would really appreciate for someone to take a look at this for me, because i am baffled!

basically, on my portfolio of work you click on it to bring up the image, but itstead it just loading the image and taking you to another page!

thanks for your help!

this is basically the code im using to create the boxes:

#### MY WORK.

```
                <ul class="cols clearFix">

                    <li>
                        <div class="clearFix">
                            <h2 class="floatLeft">Circle Cover</h2>
                            <a href="./" class="more floatLeft">Website</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="./tmp/circlecover_2.jpg" class="thumb">
                            <span class="zoom"></span>
                            <img src="./tmp/circlecover_1.jpg" alt="No image" />
                        </a>
                        <p>Circle Cover provides travel insurance for the over 50's. My main aims were to keep the site clean, simple and easy to navigate. With mobile compaitibility. 
                        </p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="center">
                        <div class="clearFix">
                            <h2 class="floatLeft">Virgin Insurance</h2>
                            <a href="./" class="more floatLeft">Website</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="./tmp/virgin_2.jpg" class="thumb">
                            <span class="zoom"></span>
                            <img src="./tmp/virgin_1.jpg" alt="No image" />
                        </a>
                        <p>Re-design of the Virgin Travel Insurance quote website. It does its job in effectively helping customers buy insurance online, taking them through the quote process.</p>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="clearFix">
                            <h2 class="floatLeft">Victoria's Salon</h2>
                            <a href="./" class="more floatLeft">website</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="./tmp/tanning_2.jpg" class="thumb">
                            <span class="zoom"></span>
                            <img src="./tmp/tanning_1.jpg" alt="No image" />
                        </a>
                        <p>A small salon requested a website to help promote the business online. Modern and girly was the theme, keeping it suited to its target audience. </p>
                    </li>

                                            <li>
                        <div class="clearFix">
                            <h2 class="floatLeft">MPM Property</h2>
                            <a href="./" class="more floatLeft">Website</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="./tmp/mpm_2.jpg" class="thumb">
                            <span class="zoom"></span>
                            <img src="./tmp/mpm_1.jpg" alt="No image" />
                        </a>
                        <p>MPM Property group requested a site which simply informs the public what they do. The site has a simple and precise layout encorporating the company style. </p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="center">
                        <div class="clearFix">
                            <h2 class="floatLeft">Twine Rooms Design</h2>
                            <a href="./" class="more floatLeft">Concept</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="./tmp/twine_2.jpg" class="thumb">
                            <span class="zoom"></span>
                            <img src="./tmp/twine_1.jpg" alt="No image" />
                        </a>
                        <p>A minimalistic design using a consistent colour scheme and layout, with a fresh and colourful feel. Plenty of white space to make the main features stand out.</p>
                    </li>
```

Comment: http://debug-my-code-for-me.com

Comment: Where's your code to create the Fancyboxes? I don't see it.

Comment: Hi @user2592039. Stack Overflow isn't a code inspection service, even if you say please. Please edit your answer to include a reduced example of the code that's problematic.

Comment: OP, we need the jQuery code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: Thanks, which jQuery should i get rid of?

Comment: The one you don't need :p

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix**: Remove the jQuery script tag from your footer on line 343.

**Better Fix**: Also change line 15 from

```
<script src="./js/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```